# Should I add WHERE when setting values to constant?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Will the next command work faster if I uncomment the third line?

```
UPDATE "Users"
SET "Type"=0
-- WHERE "Type"<>0
```

Comment: Yes unless you want unnecessary row updates (which then also mean index updates). Consider a case where you have a table with a million rows, only one of which fits the criteria of `Type <> 0`. 1 rows updated vs a million rows updated.

Comment: Speed aside, keep in mind that the semantics of these statements are different if `Type` has `NULL` values.

Comment: Yep; it should be `WHERE type IS DISTINCT FROM 0`.

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command will be faster (at least not slower) for the following reasons:

- It has to modify fewer rows.
- It has to add fewer index entries.
- Any `ON UPDATE` trigger will fire fewer times.